# How do I put commands into my config file in irssi?

Tags: irssi

If I want a command like the following to be run when I start up irssi, how can I do it?
Just putting it on a line by itself does not work.

```
/ignore -channels #chan1,#chan2,#chan3 * JOINS PARTS QUITS NICKS
```

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is *you don't*. The config file doesn't take commands, it takes configuration, and everything you do with `/ignore` is saved in the configuration *anyway* so you don't need to automate it. There's a whole section for it:

```
ignores = (
    { level = "JOINS PARTS QUITS NICKS";
      channels = ( "#chan1", "#chan2", "#chan3" ); }
);
```

---

The wrong answer is `~/.irssi/startup`.